# Individual user access setting for list view settings

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, permissions

While configuring ‘custom view’ for Share point list, I am trying to customise view for each user, such that each user can view his/her customized view only. Please share tips, how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you cannot set permission for views in SharePoint 2010 Therefore, if you have impression that each view should only be viewed by respective user then you have to use Sharepoint designer to do the trick.

1. First you create a document library.
2. Create the view for the user.
3. Use the SharePoint designer to copy the view file to document library.
4. stop inheriting permission on Sharepoint document library and delete form source library
5. give permission to the view file for the user inside document library.

Hope this helps